# Separate interfaces and implementation emf ecore

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, e4, emf

Imagine the following situation: we have bundle `A` with interface `IntA` defined in emf model and bundle `B` with class `classB`. When we generate code from the emf model in the bundle `A` we will get `IntA` and `IntAImpl` files which contain interface declaration and implementation respectively.

Now suppose that we want that some method implementation in `IntAImpl` could work with class `classB`. We need to add bundle `B` to required bundles of the bundle `A`. We also want that `classB` could operate with interface `IntA` from bundle `A`. That makes us to add bundle `A` to the required bundles of bundle `B`. We've just got cyclic dependency.

Everything would have been fine if interfaces and implementation had been declared in the different bundles - say, `A.int` and `A.impl`. In this way, `B` and `A.impl` would have had dependency from `A.int` and `A.impl` would have had dependency from `B` - no cycle.

Now comes the question - is it possible to make emf generate interfaces and implementations in different bundles? If not then how is it supposed to deal with this kind of a problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is an old post from 2008 that answers this question:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=134600/

In short: it is not possible.

In any case, you state that "IntAImpl *could* work with class classB". So, is this a theoretic situation you have in mind that will not happen or are you sure this situation will happen?

Comment: Sometimes I get cyclic dependencies which arise on the same basis as described. Yes, in practice there is always a way to redesign your classes to get rid of cyclic dependencies. But there wouldn't be any dependencies if implementation and interfaces were separate from the beginning so I just wonder why they are not.

Comment: I saw this post but restricting exported packages doesn't solve the problem discribed in my question.